# Disable button based on product availability

Tags: jquery, angularjs, onsen-ui

I need to disable the ons-button based on {{product.Availability}}, if it is 'Out of Stock',I need to disable the ons-button. How do I work it out. I'm using Onsen-UI framework.

```
<div>
...
<tr><td align="left">Availability:</td><td align="left">{{product.Availability}}</td>
...
</div>
<ons-button modifier="large--cta">Add to Cart</ons-button>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normal form elements `ng-disabled` can be used to disable them, however the `<ons-button>` tag doesn't implement `ng-disabled` but we  can use `ng-attr-disabled` instead. Like this

```
  <ons-button ng-attr-disabled="{{ disabled }}">Button</ons-button>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="disabled">
```

The button will be disabled when the checkbox is checked. The `ng-disabled` attribute will be added in the next version of Onsen UI.

In your case you can do

```
<div>
...
<tr><td align="left">Availability:</td><td align="left">{{product.Availability}}</td>
...
</div>
<ons-button modifier="large--cta" ng-attr-disabled="{{ product.Availability === 'Out of Stock' }}">Add to Cart</ons-button>
```

I made a small example: http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/bNwWQz

Answer (score 0):

you can check if your model matches to a particular string in ng-disabled,

```
<div>
...
<tr><td align="left">Availability:</td><td align="left">{{product.Availability}}</td>
...
</div>
<ons-button modifier="large--cta" ng-disabled="product.Availability=='Out of Stock'">Add to Cart</ons-button>
```

This will disable the button if the value for `product.Availability == Out of Stock`

here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/9480/

Comment: Thanks @NaeemShaikh, but as AndreasArgelius said, this code doesn't have any effect on Ons-button. Thanks again friend.